# Symfony/GuzzleHttp: Limiting API calls across multiple consumers/instances

Tags: php, symfony, limit, guzzle

I've been working on a project for a while that fetches data from an API and processes that data locally for various uses. Currently, a consumer picks up JSON objects from the message queue that it uses to trigger a matching Symfony command. The rate limiting is built in to this one consumer, is fairly simple and adjusts itself automatically to status responses from the API. The problem is, the way it is set up, it cannot run in parallel and if there is a major update to the versioned static data on the API, all processing halts while it caches the new static data.

I looked at using the `rabbitmq-bundle` Symfony bundle and converting the commands into separate consumers with their own channels so that they can be run in parallel and no longer block each other, however this comes with a couple of issues I'm stuck with how to handle.

The first is that I still need to manage limiting the API calls across all the consumers. I have a wrapper for Guzzle that could, in theory, use a simple file to manage to number of calls across all instances of it. I looked at an existing token bucket library but setting it up to work in Symfony looks problematic as each consumer could potentially reset the number of tokens if the consumer is restarted, so... Not sure where to go with that.

The second is that some consumers may hit data from the main API that we're still do not have the matching version of the static data for. If this happens, it needs to trigger the related consumers but only if there isn't already a trigger in each queue... Possible solution I can see for this is record the latest requested version in a file at the time a message is published to update it and have the consumer wait for the data to be available locally. Again, kind of lost about how best to handle this.